# Limit Voltage to Load

Tags: voltage, batteries, voltage-regulator, charger

In this circuit, either the battery or the charger will be powering the load depending on the voltage of the battery. The problem is that both battery and charger can potentially be 16.8 V sources and the load can only tolerate 14.5 V max.

[image: block diagram]

In a circuit like this, is it possible to limit the voltage to the load from charger/battery to 14.5 V, while still allowing the battery to charge to its maximum 16.8 V? I'm using a Li-ion battery and cannot change to LiFePO4 because I need high energy density.

Answer (score 3):

Use a voltage regulator between the charger/battery and the load. You say the load can tolerate a maximum of 14.5 volts so, if it nominally requires 12 volts, use a standard 12 volt regulator.

If you need to be able to produce 12 volts when battery and charger are only delivering (say) 13 volts, then use a low drop-out voltage regulator.

If the current/amperage requirements for the load are above 1 amp then consider using a buck switching regulator with capability to work down to 13 volts.

If the current/amperage requirements for the load are above 1 amp and the charger/battery may drop below 12 volts, use a buck-boost switching regulator.